# Multiplying rectangular complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Is this correct below?

$$ A \times B = (4 + i1) (2 + i3) $$

$$ = (4)(2) + (i1)(i3) + (i1)(2) + (4)(i3) $$

$$ = 8 + (i^2 3) + i(2) + (i12) $$

$$ = 8 +((-1)3) + i2 + i12 $$

$$= 8 + 3 + i2 + i12 $$

$$ = 11 + i14 $$

So $A \times B = 11 + 14i$.

Is this the correct answer and method of getting the right answer?

Comment: No, it isn't  Why do you say $(-1)3=3$ instead of $-3?$

Comment: Use $12i$ instead of $i12$. It's also $3x$ not $x3$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple mistake in the 5th line. It will be:
$$8+((-1)3)+14i=8-3+14i=5+14i$$

Comment: Can i ask what the difference is between the i before the number or after the number? Does this matter? How should i place the i?

Comment: It doesn't matter. But writing $i$ later looks better :) Can I know in which class you are now?

Comment: Thank you. College

Comment: Then you can think complex plane like a vector space with basis $\{1,i\}$. And $3i$ will mean $3$ steps toward the imaginary axis.